In arm-none-eabi-gdb how the cortex-M peripherals can be accessed using .SVD file?
I am trying to make a baremetal project using cortex-M0 processor in ubuntu. In the layout window the registers are visible but for the mcu peripherals .SVD file needs to read and displayed.
I tried for some help and followed steps as per the urls :
https://github.com/bnahill/PyCortexMDebug
https://yairgadelov.me/using-svd-file-in-gdb-for-cortex-m-debugging/
Still the GDB environment failed to understand the SVD commands(svd_load) as described in the websites above.
Is there any other utility to achieve this or any better way other than this?
Thanks

You should give more details.  The links you gave suggest two different approaches, so which one did you take?  Did GDB give any errors?  Do you mean GDB didn't have he svd_load command?  Or the command didn't load the .svd file correctly?  You should detail exactly what you did, show the contents of any files you edited, and then show the complete output of your GDB session.  After that we might be able to help.

@Andrew. There is no inbuilt command for svd file handling in arm-none-eabi-gdb. The 1st link I have shared is for PyCortexMDebug. The 2nd link is pointing to PyCortexMDebug only with some additional commands which needs to be saved in .gdbinit. If you had seen the links, you wouldn't be commenting for 2 different approaches. Blindly don't come here and comment, first go through the details. If you had worked on arm-none-eabi-gdb, no more details you need other than what I had shared. Don't waste my and your time here.
